# Send AJAX return error when data is string

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a simple code that sends data to the action and returns the same data to AJAX. Here is my jQuery code:

```
  $('.calculateField').on('input', function (e) {

    var requestData = $('.calculateField').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: '/InsurancePolicyContract/CalculatePurePrice',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        success: function (response) {
            $('#test1').text(response);
        },
        error: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        },
        failure: function (response) {
            alert(response.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

and here is my backend code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult CalculatePurePrice([FromBody]string TotalPrice)
    {
        return Ok(TotalPrice);
    }
```

the problem is when I change my send-data (requestData) to string (ex: `"test"`) it says "parse error" and run error function in AJAX body! but when it was an integer(ex:548) it works to find and success method runs! Why?

Comment: If your data is not json, your `contentType` should not be `application/json`

Comment: @Taplar It's still JSON since he sends `JSON.stringify(requestData)`.

Comment: `.val()` returns a string, so it's already a string. I suspect the problem is that your back-end code expects it to be a string that can be parsed as a number, and `test` won't work.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify your Action method like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CalculatePurePrice([FromBody]string TotalPrice)
{
    return Json(TotalPrice, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `Accept` header in your ajax request. Then your backend will give proper json or it will return plain text.

$('.calculateField').on('input', function (e) {

```
var requestData = $('.calculateField').val();

$.ajax({
    url: '/InsurancePolicyContract/CalculatePurePrice',
    type: 'POST',
    data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
    headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json"
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (response) {
        $('#test1').text(response);
    },
    error: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    },
    failure: function (response) {
        alert(response.responseText);
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 0):

For your issue, it is caused by `dataType: 'json'` which is telling jQuery what kind of response to expect. For plain test without `""`, it will fail to convert to json. If you enter `"test"` in the input, it will work, but if you enter `test` directly, it will fail since there is no extra `""`.

For a workaround, you could remove `dataType: 'json'` like

```
    $.ajax({
            url: '/api/movie/CalculatePurePrice',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(requestData),
            //dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (response) {
                    $('#test1').text(response);
            },
            error: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
            },
            failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
            }
    });
```